# BI Publisher - ignore section - based on info from XML input data

Tags: xml, rtf, bi-publisher, xml-publisher, oracle-xml-publisher

I have the following scenario:

I'm developing a rtf report in BIP desktop 11 containing 3 sections: intro, content, ending.
Based on xml input data, each section may generate one or multiple pages.
Because each section has it's own unique header and footer, I divided the rtf into 3 sections (with MS Word tool Page Layout -> Breaks -> Section Breaks - Next Page).

.. all of this let's say for an Active client. (first tag from XML is Active/Inactive)

If the client is Inactive the report should generate an empty one-page pdf.
Here's the problem: For inactive clients, report generates 3 blank pages (because document is split into 3 sections).
Any thougths on how to fix that? Maybe a different approach in dividing the sections?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by using the following code:

Intro

```
<?for-each@section:Client[Status='Active']?>
```

...

Content

...

Ending

...

```
<?end for-each?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `if` condition before the page break, and then `end if` after the section, before the next page break. in the if condition, check if the `status = Active`

Comment: I have tried the following code sample but it does not go over the page breakes.
<?for-each:Client?>
<?if:Status='Active'?>
... [content + page brakes]
<?end if?>
<end for-each>